# How automatically change to different program when a button is pressed in Python

Tags: python

**I'd like for my first program to automatically switch over to a second program when a button is pressed.**

I tried break and sys.exit() but that put me back at the command line, which I don't want to I'm trying to eliminate having to use the mouse and keyboard to change to a different program.

The programs are for a microcomputer that will be doing the same tasks many times a day; I don't want to have a keyboard or mouse connected after the installation.

Comment: If there's no keyboard connected, how are you going to press the button?

Comment: There will be one large button connected to a GPIO pin, which this computer has.

Comment: Does this behaviour make sense from a requirements (functionality) point-of-view? "The programs are for a microcomputer that will be doing the same tasks many times a day" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The microcomputer will be in a sealed metal box to protect it from molten steel splash. It will record the voltage produced from a thermocouple, put into a formula and then show the result on a monitor. I don't want to have to protect a keyboard and mouse in this harsh environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may encapsulate the second program in a function, and call the function from your first program.  Alternatively, if the second program resides in its own module, you may import that module.  Importing the module will execute the code inside of it.

Comment: Unless the code in the module is in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, like is often the case for well-designed modules. It's better to import a module ahead of time and execute code in it later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module for this. Create a `Popen` object for the script you want triggered, and then exit the parent process without waiting for the child to complete:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def on_button_pressed():
    subprocess.Popen(["path/to/script", "arg1", "arg2"], shell=False)
    sys.exit()
```